# Maintaining Cassandra Cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-0.7

1) What are the things that one should practice to maintain Cassandra cluster properly?

2) As explained here:[Apache Cassandra at Clearspring](http://www.datastax.com/events/cassandranyc2011/presentations/burroughs), they are doing rolling restart in a week or two.

3) How does rolling restart help in maintaining Cluster? Is there any specific activities (Cleaning) that Cassandra does while restarting?

Answer (score 0):

The only real generic rule is that you must run nodetool repair at least every gc_grace_seconds to avoid deleted data reappearing.  Otherwise, general monitoring of your cluster using cfstats, iostat, etc., is always a good idea.